# Completed Zeta Function - Edwards Section 1.8 - I'm Stuck on a Step

Tags: complex-analysis

In H.M. Edwards book *Riemann's Zeta Function*, he develops a representation of the completed zeta function in Section 1.8.  I am stuck on the "easy" step, so I must have a case of mathematical blindness.  The function $\psi(x)$ has an inversion formula:

$$2\psi(x)+1=x^{-1/2}[2\psi(1/x)+1]$$

Edwards says that "now differentiation of [the above]"..."easily gives":

$$1/2+\psi(1)+4\psi'(1)=0$$

When I differentiate both sides, I get:

$$2\psi'(x)=x^{-1/2}[2\psi'(1/x)]-\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}[2\psi(1/x)+1]$$
$$=x^{-1/2}[2\psi'(1/x)]-\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}[2\psi(1/x)]-\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}$$

Now let $x=1=1/x$ and we have:

$$2\psi'(1)=2\psi'(1)-\psi(1)-1/2$$

As you see, I am "almost" there.  I just needed a minus sign on the RHS $2\psi'(1)$.  Where is my blind spot?  Thank you.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} \psi(1/x) = \psi'(1/x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x} = -\psi'(x)x^{-2}$ by the chain rule (assuming that I have not flipped a sign somewhere or done something else stupid in my computation).  That should give you your sign.  At any rate, the take home message is: Chain Rule.

Comment: Are you kidding ? You don't even give the definition of your function $\psi(x)$ (which is  $\frac{\theta(x) -1}{2}, \theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ so that $\int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} \psi(x)dx = \pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not completely applied the chain rule.
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (2 \psi(1/x)+1) \neq 2 \psi'(1/x)  \text{.}  $$
Instead, \begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (2 \psi(1/x)+1) 
    &= 2 \psi'(1/x) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(1/x)  \\
    &= 2 \psi'(1/x) \frac{-1}{x^2}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
This is where your missing minus sign is.

Comment: Thank you all. An embarrassing over site.  I got sucked in by 1=x=1/x.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the chain rule when you differentitate $ \psi( \frac{1}{x})$
\begin{eqnarray*}
2\psi'(x)=\color{red}{-x^{-5/2}}[2\psi'(1/x)]-\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}[2\psi(1/x)+1]
\end{eqnarray*}